# How to handle code modification on the client side?

Tags: asp.net

We’ve implemented a form with a button and a couple of hidden fields that when clicked it posts to a URL on our server. One of these hidden fields is a specific return code that we read in the back end to know that the user pressed this button.

The problem we have in this scenario is that this result code in the hidden field can be changed using Firebug or another devtool on the client side to send another code that triggers something completely different in the back end.

The question is, what can we do in the back end to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can't influence what the client sends, so you need to handle the values on the server side.

You need to match the other values sent in the request with your return code in order to detect an invalid state.

**Simple example:**

If the return code is `1`, you expect to receive the parameters `a` and `b`. If they are not set, the request is invalid.

Or the other way round, if you get the parameters `a` and `b`, but the return code is `2`, the request is also invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But say you always send only a and b in the response together with the return code. How could you possibly know that the return code has been altered?

Comment: On the server side you are not able to know whether the return code got altered. You always need to be able to distinguish invalid request parameters from valid ones. So you need to check the values of all parameters you expect for a specific request. If you always get `a` and `b` as parameters, you still need to check if their values are valid. So e.g. if you have return code 1, you expect parameter `a` to be `house` or `flat` and parameter `b` to be between `1` and `100`.